# Increase Autocomplete scrollbar size

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, scrollbar

I am creating a application for touchscreen device. The size of the scrollbar available with autocomplete is so user friendly. How to increase the size of the scrollbar in the autocomplete. [JQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)

Geetha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the [`scrollHeight` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions). I would suggest using the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) instead, as it's much more flexible (I recently made the switch).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by modifying the height of .ui-autocomplete . If u have fixed number of items in the list then You can set this by setting property.

If your list varies , Then you can use max-height property . This works fine in all latest browsers except in IE. In IE also it works if you mention doctype i.e standards mode